# Creating a game, where characters have outlines like in Brawl Stars

Tags: copyright

If my game would have outlines on the characters just like  in the mobile game Brawl Stars, but with a completely different implementation (I sure hope so. I mean, I don't have access to their codebase to check), and the characters themselves look completely different. Would this cause legal issues?

The intent is to create a cartoon effect, rather than just copying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is fine.

Copyright covers creative expression, not ideas. The sprite is copyrightable, the idea of "a black outline would make things look cartoony" is not- even if Brawl Stars had been the first to do it.